# Can UILongPressGestureRecognizer and UISwipeGestureRecognizer be used together?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have the following code which creates four gestures:

```
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UIPanGestureRecognizer * panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[panGesture setDelegate:self];
[self addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

UILongPressGestureRecognizer * longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.00;
[self addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeUp:)];
swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[self addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeDown:)];
swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
[self addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];
```

The Pan and LongPress work fine, but I never get either of the Swipe gestures. Is there something special I need to do to have the swipe selectors get called?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just answered this [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899299/957768).

Short form: a swipe gesture is a special case of a pan gesture, and by default no two gestures will recognize simultaneously. Look into `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` and/or `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:`. You'll find further help for this and related issues in [Apple's guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html).

Comment: LOL, yes you did.  I did read through the doc, and I see the problem, although I could not find confirmation.  If you notice my code above, I set the LongTap minimumPressDuration to 0.00. When I do this and I set a breakpoint at both gestures, Pan and Swipe, it only breaks on Pan. However, if I sent the minimumPressDuration to 0.125, 1/4 sec. it breaks at both. I could not find anything that explained this so I am at a loos as to why the pressDuration matters.  But, yes, your solution works for the most part.