# Changing UIView to new position using UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

I'm using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to slide my `UIView` up the screen, but I can't figure out how to set its position so that it stays up at the top of the screen until i swipe it back down.  Right now I can swipe it up, but it will fall back down right away.  Should I be doing a transform instead of `CGRectOffset`?

```
- (IBAction)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    if(recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)
    {

        panedView.frame =CGRectOffset( panedView.frame, 0, -1*self.view.bounds.size.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Yes I am.  Should I not be?

Comment: Sure but that's the problem. You cannot change the frame of a view controlled by auto layout. Auto layout sets the frame. That is what auto layout is.

Comment: I just tested it with auto layout turned off and I'm still encountering the same issue

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you showed. Other code, or auto layout, is moving the view back.

Comment: I can hold the view in place, if I hold the gesture.  But as soon as the gesture ends, the view falls back down.

Comment: You're right.  I have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on the same view.  When its disabled, the view stays where I want it.  Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: You must mediate between them. In all probability, the pan gesture recognizer must require the swipe gesture recognizer to fail ("fail" means "you go first"). You can do this directly or (better) use the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate methods.

Comment: I tried both `-(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) panGesture shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer: (UISwipeGestureRecognizer*) swipeGesture` 
AND 
`-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGesture shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGesture`.
I guess this is going to require a lot of trial and error to figure out

Comment: It should work if you're doing it right. (Remember that there are LOT of other gesture recognizer that are going to be sent to those methods!) Or follow the direct method, as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21728621/341994 However, as that answer points out, you've done a difficult thing, in that pan and swipe are almost the same, so you're introducing a delay into the pan that you might not like.