# Getting UIPanGesture and UISwipeGesture working together in the same direction

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

I've set up my `UIView` to call a method when the view is panned up and to call some other method when the view is swiped up.  My pan works fine and I can keep my pan disabled if my velocity.y is above a certain limit, but I can never get the swipe action to work when my pan fails.  I've tried playing around with the delegate methods without much luck.  Looked over this solution but no luck: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21728621/1925859

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer * panRec = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    panRec.delegate = self;
    [panedView addGestureRecognizer:panRec];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeRec = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    swipeRec.delegate = self;
    [panedView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRec];

    [swipeRec requireGestureRecognizerToFail:panRec];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
        CGPoint velocity = [pan velocityInView:gestureRecognizer.view];
        if (ABS(velocity.y) > 200)
        {

            NSLog(@"Swipe actiavted");
            return NO;
        }
    }
        return YES;  
}

 - (IBAction)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"In Swipe");
     if(recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)
    {
        panedView.frame =CGRectOffset( panedView.frame, 0, -1*self.view.bounds.size.height*.80);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should (a) specify direction of swipe gesture when you instantiate it (it gets you out of having to worry about the velocity of the pan); and (b) make the pan require the swipe to fail, rather than the other way around. You might not even need that delegate method anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove your delegate method, add direction to the swipe and change the receiver of `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` then it will work. Note that pans must be way slower than sweeps in order to be recognized.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer * panRec = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [panedView addGestureRecognizer:panRec];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeRec = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

    swipeRec.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    [panedView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRec];

    [panRec requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeRec];
}


- (IBAction)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"In Swipe");
    if(recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)
    {
        panedView.frame =CGRectOffset( panedView.frame, 0, -1*self.view.bounds.size.height*.80);
    }
}

- (IBAction)handlePan:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"PAN");
}
```

Comment: Works!  Why get rid of `swipeRec.delegate = self` and `panRec.delegate=self`?

Comment: Well you could keep those, but I removed them since they're not necessary for this particular purpose.