# panGestureRecogniser and table cell delete

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm having a bit of a problem with a clash of functions of sorts. I am using SWRevealViewController to create a sidebar and this works with the following line:

```
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer());
```

However, this is working on the same page as a `TableView` where swiping left on the rows allows a delete button to function.

IF I have the panGestureRecogniser working then the delete button on the table cells doesn't work because it's difficult to swipe precisely for it. If I comment out this line of code, then the swipe for delete works perfectly.

Is there any way I can have both these features working seamlessly together?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe it may be linked to the following:

[Adding a UIPanGestureRecognizer and a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to same view causes conflicts after setting requireGestureToFail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723932/adding-a-uipangesturerecognizer-and-a-uiswipegesturerecognizer-to-same-view-caus)

However, I am not sure how to implement this with my code and the default swipe in table cells (as I'm not really calling a UISwipeGesture anywhere)