# Make Pan gesture require all 4 swipe gestures to fail

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipangesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have all 4 *Swipe gestures* registered for my view (*Swipe up, down, left and right*). I would also like to use the *Pan gesture* for the same view, but `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` allows me to specify only one of the *Swipe gestures*.

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
[panGesture requireGestureRecognizersToFail: @[swipeUp, swipeDown, swipeLeft, swipeRight]];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, Take a brief look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898627/what-is-the-difference-between-pan-and-swipe-in-ios)

If I get u right, u want pan gesture, so:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:myView 
                                                                             action:@selector(handlePan:)];

[myView addGestureRecognizer: panGesture];
```

Then, in `handlePan:` u should:

```
- (void) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint translation = [uiPanGestureRecognizer translationInView:self.superview];
    myView.center = CGPointMake(lastLocation.x + translation.x,
                              lastLocation.y + translation.y);
}
```

Comment: Thats not what I was asking for. It looks like there is no way for me to achieve what I am looking for. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call it multiple times like so:

```
[panGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeUp];
[panGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeDown];
[panGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeLeft];
[panGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeRight];
```