# swift UISwipeGestureRecognizer and UIPanGestureRecognizer at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

```
    var panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "pan:");
    var swipeGestureLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipe:");

    swipeGestureLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left;

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGestureLeft);
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture);
```

When i run it only the pan gesture gets triggered. If don't add the pan gesture to the view then the swipe gesture works like it should.

Comment: read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898627/what-is-the-difference-between-pan-and-swipe-in-ios