# Swipe to navigate to another ViewController and change according to finger movements

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I need to navigate to another view controller when swipe (left, right, up, down). And the other view controller should change according to the user finger movement, not to change view controller with in given time. I used

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9, animations: { () -> Void in
```

but it used a duration, so does not change according to user movement.

Comment: it doesn't have much information about how to do this :(

Answer (score 1):

`UISwipeGestureRecognizer` is not the proper gesture recognizer you should use here. If you want to change the content when user is doing some gestures (movements), you have to use `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. With pan gesture recognizer, you can track the position of the gesture in the view, and change the view accordingly.

Comment: Info backing this up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898627/what-is-the-difference-between-pan-and-swipe-in-ios