# Gesture priorities in Message app extension

Tags: ios, swift, imessage, imessage-extension

I'm building an iMessage app extension and would like to add some panGestures to a subview in my controller.

In compact mode (not an issue in expanded mode), this causes the iMessage app to swap the view across other 3rd party apps. Obviously, I don't want to block users from swapping to other apps entirely, but for a small portion of the view (a small rectangular subview) I would like to have my gesture recognizer take priority.

I've tried using shouldBeRequiredToFailBy, but it seems like this method is never triggered with recognizers that are not within my root controller view. In other words, I have no control on whether I can block the gestures coming outside my app. Is there anyway I can have the panGesture take priority in some scenarios?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Looks like the default ["Digital Touch" app](https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/iOS/ios10-iphone6s-messages-imessage-digital-touch-send-digital-sketch.png) allows some sort of horizontal gestures to block the swiping between apps. I'd like to accomplish something like this but not sure how to do it?

Comment: This seems like a conflict between Pan and Swipe gestures, have you tried resolve it accordingly to this post for example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899299/3677394

Moreover, you can try to differ between gesture sources/types, see here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/preferring_one_gesture_over_another